# Highcharts - Legend style from CSS, Firefox issue

Tags: highcharts

I am using multiple of Highcharts which has different `legend y` value position for each chart for some reason.

As I want to generalize for all the charts, I am trying to control all the y values from css like below...

```
.highcharts-legend-item rect{y:3;}
```

The above css is working great as expected in Chrome alone.. **not working in Firefox**

I can do that by going to each chart and alter the `legend: {y:3}`, but because of less control on server code I am not able to do the same.

Is there any other way to do the same for Firefox please?

http://jsfiddle.net/1h91po8b/1/

Comment: Could you update your code with current charts, because I see single chart and in both cases (Chrome / Firefox) look like the same. Which version of FF do you have ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan... updated the fiddle.. please find the link

http://jsfiddle.net/1h91po8b/1/

Comment: For me it still does not work in chrome too. When I remove CSS styles, legend is printed in the same way. The key is that you need to have the legend in the same place in all charts, am I right ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan... yes, exactly... The legend has to be in same place for all the charts and need to able to control by **CSS**... above example is just a dummy...

Comment: Let my know why by CSS, but not by y parameter? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.y ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan, as I said it in my post, I do not have control over server side script (Client's server - They are not willing to give the access to code)... That is the reason, I am looking for CSS

Comment: All right, you don't have an access to JS files, but can you add extra Javascript or not and you can only edit CSS ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan, I can add extra js file to the site... PS: Not to the existing js file :(